# Getting an HTTP 403 error on a request with NodeJS when it works with Python, cURL,

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to issue a POST request using NodeJS that contains Json data but I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error.

The thing I don't understand is that the same request is working just fine when I issue it using different other languages/software like cURL, Python and Postman.

To do so I'm using the request package and the automatically generated Postman code :

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': apiDomain,
  body: myPayload

};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

But as mention above it keeps returning a 403 error.
I also tried sending the request using axios, request-promise packages, but same problem, even with the `X-Requested-With` header which was mentioned in other StackOverlow topics.

I noticed that it's working and it returns the wanted data when request is configured to use the Fiddler Everywhere proxy, which is done by the setting the following options :

```
ca: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/FiddlerCertificate.cer").toString(),
rejectUnauthorized: false,
agent: new HttpsProxyAgent("http://127.0.0.1:8866")
```

The only difference between the postman request (which works) and the NodeJS request is the "Connection: keep-alive" header which is present in the request done using NodeJS...

**EDIT** : The problem might come from TLS. But that doesn't explain why NodeJS isn't doing things automatically like cURL or Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
By analyzing packets using Wireshark and Fiddler, I noticed that NodeJS uses TLSv1.3 when Postman uses TLSv1.2. This is what caused the difference between the tools I used to test.

To force NodeJS request and request-promise modules to work with TLSv1.2, you just have to add the following to your request options object :

```
agentOptions: {
    secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method'
}
```

Comment: You're writing "TSL" but did you mean "TLS"?  _Transport Layer Security_

Comment: @Wyck Yes, TLS. I edited the answer, thanks!